# Interceptor in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, rest, authentication, token

I have some troubles with setting header for my REST app.
I need to set authorization token to authorization header and actually i use this code:

```
app.factory('sessionInjector', ['$log','$rootScope', function($log, $rootScope) {  
    var sessionInjector = {
        request: function(config) {

                $log.debug($rootScope.accesstoken);

                angular.forEach($rootScope.accesstoken, function(value, key) {
                    if(key=='access_token'){
                        $log.debug(value);
                        config.headers['Authorization'] = "Bearer " + value;
                    }
                });

            return config;
        }
    };
    return sessionInjector;
}]);


app.config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('sessionInjector');
}]);
```

value in forEach has right token value.

Unfortunately still don't getting resources...

Logging statements are executed, i don't see header in request. 
[image: Image with headers]
First request header is for getting token, and it's work fine, but requests for resources like second request don't send appropriate header.
For CURL this works:

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer 5314f45f-0ad0-4f3c-92c0-429c8075eea4" http://localhost:8080/categories/
```

Comment: This is looking all correct to me. Do you see any errors in console ?

Comment: Only this type errors: 1. OPTIONS http://localhost:8080/categories angular.js:9827 2.XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/categories. Invalid HTTP status code 401 (index):1

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting it with every outgoing request, probably you should set the header like this:

```
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = "Bearer " + value;
```

Comment: @KrzysztofKrólikowski I hope you tried setting it in the config method of your app module, and not inside an interceptor, something like: `.config(function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common'Authorization'] = "Bearer " + value;
    
  })`

Answer (score 0):

After one day in pain I found that implemented interceptor is working when I execute site on IE... But why ? Why I cannot set headers under Chrome or Firefox ? I tried set headers with interceptorsm with method of Himanshu and with AJAX syntax, why all of them doesnt work on these browsers ?